# i not know how sum amount decimal number using php

Tags: php

I sum some amount using php but i try this code.
for example.

```
$sum1 = "0.04000";
$sum2 = "23";
$sum3 = "30";
$sum4 = $sum2+$sum3;
$sum5 = sum4*20;
$sum6 = $sum1+$sum5;
echo $sum6;
```

When run this code.
out result show.

```
1060.04
```

but i show result this how can.

```
0.05060
```

Comment: Why do you think that should be the result?

Comment: He's missing the $ on the $sum5=sum4*20 line

Comment: @Scath That must be a copying error, because he's getting the result that's expected with the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the answer :)

```
$sum1 = 0.04000;
$sum2 = 23;
$sum3 = 30;
$sum4 = $sum2+$sum3; //53
$sum5 = $sum4*20; // 1060 (Note, added missing '$' to this var, I expect this was copy paste error as should fail)
$sum6 = $sum1+$sum5; // 1060.04
echo $sum6;
```

Comment: He's missing the $ on the $sum5=sum4*20 line

Comment: Yes, I added in, will update. This should have error'd if he has errors suitably turned on, thinking copy+paste error too :)

Comment: Yea I ran it on http://phptester.net/ and it errored but still echoed .04 I think hes getting the error and wants 1060.04 hard to understand his question though

Comment: @kako0000000 well what calculation are you doing to expect 0.05060??

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
$sum1 = "0.04000";
$sum2 = "23";
$sum3 = "30";
$sum4 = +$sum2++$sum3;
$sum5 = +$sum4*20;
$sum6 = +$sum1++$sum5;
echo $sum6;
```

This will output the expected result .